# How to make Lambda function request coming from user's IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using Lambda function that uses third-party API in NodeJS. The problem is that there is a request limit which is limited to one request per second per IP.

Since Lambda function uses same IP address (most of the time) this will cause a timeout request if there are more users using it.

I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this issue by making the request coming from user's IP instead of Lambda's IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that. As the request to 3rd party API is originating from Lambda the source IP to the 3rd party API would always be the IP where Lambda is hosted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the best practice in this kind of situation?

Comment: As you are relying on the bottleneck of 3rd party API you can't help much here. The only solution would be to request 3rd party API to increase API request load from an IP